# Is working for a weapons development firm haram?

Tags: halal-haram, work

Is it Haram to work within a company that develops military and combat equipment?

My concern is what is intended when using these weapons and of course the client will not say we are using it against a particular nation or in the event of defence only, but this is easily predictable, weapons in general cause harm but they are necessary, companies within the west are not necessary contracted with only one country but can be a few.

please clarify this for me my Muslim brothers and sister, may Allah guide us all.

Comment: Interesting question. I reckon it can be haram by the intention of negative purposes which... (not by positive intention of defending the Islamic land... Wallaho-A'alamo.

Answer (score 2):

I would like you to refer to two stories one about Prophet Moosa (pbuh) *[[Qur'an 28:15-16]](http://quran.com/28/15-16)* and the story of Prophet Davood (pbuh) *[[Qur'an 38:21-26]](http://muslimvilla.smfforfree.com/index.php?topic=2446.0)*. Both the stories imply the same thing do not hasten in taking a wise decision by listening to just one man whom you don't know and ***[rely on reason not emotions while taking a decision](http://www.joycemeyer.org/articles/ea.aspx?article=we_cant_rely_on_emotions).***

So, it would be better not to work for that company until you can make sure it's clients are the ones whom you want them to be.

Comment: as well as the mentioned verses, your last sentence can be deemed as a brief appropriate response too "it would be better not to work for that company until you can make sure it's clients are the ones whom you want them to be" (not as oppressive government...).